# IE8 hangs on document.write with "this command is not supported"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

For certain URLs (e. g. http://www.nyest.hu/iframe/240/10 ), IE8 (and older) never stops loading with the following error message: `SCRIPT123: This command is not supported.` The error line number points to a `document.write` command. IE9 and other browser load the page without problems.

Comment: Not sure about this but I believe there are some doctypes that don't support document.write. What doctype is the page?  Have you tried using a different doctype? (HTML instead of XHTML)

Comment: @GordonM: something like that, but it is the MIME type (`application/xhtml+xml`) causing the problem, not the doctype (transitional XHTML). The page is not under my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is because the page is served as XML, and [there is no `document.write` in an XML document](http://ln.hixie.ch/?count=1&start=1091626816). Other browsers throw some sort of error at the `document.write` command too, but they handle the error better and do finish loading the page.

Comment: See also the [Mozilla web developer FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#How_is_the_treatment_of_application.2fxhtml.2bxml_documents_different_from_the_treatment_of_text.2fhtml_documents.3f).