# JQuery IE Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery to make an input field switch from a text to password type on focus.  This code works fine in Chrome, but when I try to use it in IE 8 it just completely removes the field.  IE 8 returns this error:

```
This command is not supported.
jquery.min.js
Line: 16
Char: 26827
```

Here is the HTML code I am using:

```
<div id="reg_passdiv" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
<input name="reg_pass" class="inputbar italic" type="text" value="Password..." onfocus="if ($(this).attr('class') == 'inputbar italic') { $(this).attr('class', 'inputbar reg'); $(this).detach().attr('type', 'password').appendTo('#reg_passdiv'); this.value = ''; $(this).focus(); }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { $(this).attr('class', 'inputbar italic'); $(this).detach().attr('type', 'text').appendTo('#reg_passdiv'); this.value = 'Password...'; }" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this bug?  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried taking out detach()? Does not seem necessary as your just changing the attribute

Comment: You have to use it because you can't change the type of an attached input.

Comment: @Matt , ah yeah security issue in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a historically problematic issue, which you can read about in depth here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8232 . The short version is that this is simply not feasible in older IEs.

The upside is that I closed that ticket as "patchwelcome", so if you think you can tackle a reasonable fix for the issue, then we're more then happy to review and test.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is XML related problem. Not the DOCTYPE, MIME type is problem.
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248246/ie8-hangs-on-document-write-with-this-command-is-not-supported/6248267#6248267)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You can not change type of input field. The only solution is to make two fields and make interchange of values and properties between. And just show()/hide() the right field.

Comment: Yea, I did that.  Thanks, anyways :)