# jquery dynamic iframe - !document.write and IE issues

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, append, document.write

Why does this work in all browsers - except IE:

```
var $iframe = $("<iframe name=" + strFrameName +"/>");
var $doc = $iframe.contents();
$doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + opt.loadCSS + "'>");
```

However, if I use a non jquery object with document.write, it works ok in IE?

```
var $iframe = $("<iframe name=" + strFrameName +"/>");
var doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document;
doc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + opt.loadCSS + "'>");
```

I reworked a plugin, and wanted to rewrite it so that it wouldn't use `document.write`

However, now the iframe is getting created, but the head/body remain empty in IE.

see fiddle of original version (document.write):
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/Tx4Uv/

and fiddle of updated attempt to use `.append` instead of `.write`:
http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/Tx4Uv/4/

Comment: Try appending the iframe to the document before getting its contents. Most often, iframe elements won't have a `head`/`body` until appended to the DOM.

Comment: If you execute the code in the first code block after the iframe is appended to the body, it should work just fine. What version of IE is being problematic? 8 and 9?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - 8 & 9 - IE seems to only work with the `document. write` - if I use an append, the head & body remain empty and it prints the main page instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

I added a `setTimeout` of 2ms to allow the iframe to fully render (mainly for IE) before appending to head and body.